# Why is the loading of apps and websites sometimes freezing on my Android phone?

Tags: vpn, 4g, lagging

I'm using AdAway in VPN mode to block all ads on 3 phones and sometimes apps and sites won't load at all or load slowly. I'm using 4G+ and getting 50 mbps download speed. Phones are Realme Narzo 50 5G and 2 Motorola Moto G50 5G.

All sites and apps sometimes freeze during loading, like every 10
loads there is a freeze or very slow loading.

Comment: Your question is lacking detailed information, like what phones are affected and what sites you have encountered to be slow. You should also test if the network speed is the same when disabling AdAway.

Comment: Network speed is the same by doing speed test. I updated the question.

Comment: If you are trying to stop ads, then some will display as a blank screen and others may just time out - maybe that's what is looking as slowness.